# Python_LIBRARIES in CMAKE notfound

Tags: python, cmake

I installed the Qt5 and python to use it for compile Sigil using CMAKE.

First i had problems with the qt5 but i solved setting the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.
But the Python seems to have a problem with the pythonlibs and PYTHON_LIBRARIES.

First it reads in black letters:

```
Looking for python version '3.4' by checking executables: python;python3;python3.4.
Found executable C:/Users/usuario pc/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/python.exe with UNsuitable version 3.5.2
Looking for python version '3.5' by checking executables: python;python3;python3.5.
Found executable C:/Users/usuario pc/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/python.exe with suitable version 3.5.2
Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing:  PYTHON_LIBRARIES) (found suitable version "3.5.2", minimum required is "3.4")
```

And at the end in red letters it says:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.  
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:  
    PYTHON_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
linked by target "Sigil" in directory D:/Archivos de Programa/Sigil-0.9.6/src
```

Do I have to reinstall python? (which i did and reinitiate the PC). Do i have to change any line?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you installed Python including the development files, i.e. the header files?

Answer (score 1):

At first install python-dev or python3-dev using

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

and then add `-D PYTHON_LIBRARIES=<where that libpython<version>m.so is located there>` as a parameter of cmake command

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by installing python dependencies as described in [Sigil linux build instructions](https://github.com/Sigil-Ebook/Sigil/blob/master/docs/Building_on_cutting_edge_Linux.md#python):
sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-pip python3-tk python3-lxml python3-six

Comment: link is outdated

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-pip python3-tk python3-lxml python3-six
```

Worked for me ;)